# Обобщение функций javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

Есть картинки которые сортируются с помощью isotop.
Мне нужно по клику открывать модальное окно с видео. Подходящий плагин я подобрал. Теперь моя проблема в том, чтобы видео не только открывалось но и гасилось при закрытии модального окна.

```
  <div id="popup_name" class="popup_block">
    <div id="for_frame" class="for_frame">    </div>
</div>
```

В блок с `id="for_frame"` с помощью javascript я вставляю следующую конструкцию в зависимости от количества изображений:

```js
function showFun2() {
    var SummDok = document.getElementById('for_frame2'),
        SummSumm='<a  onclick="closeFun2()" title="Close" class="close" id="close2" style="color: black">X</a> <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/buEh7kKYBuA?autoplay=1" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="1" height="500" width="100%"></iframe>';
    SummDok.innerHTML = SummSumm
}
function closeFun2(){
    var SummDok = document.getElementById('for_frame2'),
        SummSumm='';
    SummDok.innerHTML = SummSumm
}
function showFun3() {
    var SummDok = document.getElementById('for_frame3'),
        SummSumm=' <a href="#close" onclick="closeFun3()" title="Close" class="close" id="close3" style="color: black">X</a> <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/buEh7kKYBuA?autoplay=1" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="1" height="500" width="100%"></iframe>';
    SummDok.innerHTML = SummSumm
}
function closeFun3(){
    var SummDok = document.getElementById('for_frame3'),
        SummSumm='';
    SummDok.innerHTML = SummSumm
```

Но я понимаю, что это не есть хорошо. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне принимать по `onclick` значения разных `id`, если они отличаются лишь цифрой?(`for_frame#`,где `#` - нужная цифра)
И каким образом объединить запросы от всех этих блоков к функции `closeFun#` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне принимать по онклику значения разных
>   id, если они отличаются лишь цифрой?(for_frame#,где # - нужная цифра)
>   И каким образом объединить запросы от всех этих блоков к функции
>   closeFun#

```
$(".test_img").on("click", function() {

  var id = $(this).attr("rel");
  $(id).html('<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close_img" rel=' + id + ' style="color: black">X</a> <iframe id="iframe' + id + '" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/buEh7kKYBuA?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1 allowfullscreen="" frameborder="1" height="500" width="100%"></iframe>');
});

$(document).on("click", ".close_img", function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("rel");
  $(id).html('');
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup_name1" class="popup_block">
  <div id="for_frame1" class="for_frame"></div>
</div>

<div id="popup_name2" class="popup_block">
  <div id="for_frame2" class="for_frame"></div>
</div>

<div id="popup_name3" class="popup_block">
  <div id="for_frame3" class="for_frame"></div>
</div>

<img src="https://www.google.ru/logos/doodles/2015/george-booles-200th-birthday-5636122663190528.2-hp.gif" class="test_img" rel="#for_frame1">
<img src="https://www.google.ru/logos/doodles/2015/george-booles-200th-birthday-5636122663190528.2-hp.gif" class="test_img" rel="#for_frame2">
<img src="https://www.google.ru/logos/doodles/2015/george-booles-200th-birthday-5636122663190528.2-hp.gif" class="test_img" rel="#for_frame3">
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oza0jha7/)

Comment: Спасибо большое, думаю я дальше справлюсь)